# Python saving into specific directory based on user input

Tags: python, input

I have trying to save images into a directory based on user input. For example:

```
if user enters 'A'
    save in A folder
elif user enters 'B'
    save in B folder
```

and so on.

When I try this two things happen one the folder doesn't fill up and two my loop goes to pieces. I have been trying for a little while with getch() and input() but both are simply not working for me.

here is my code.

```
getInput = input("Enter Which Window to Save")

if getInput == int('1'):

    cardFound = input("Which Card was Found: ")
    cardsFound.append(cardFound)

    print("\tFlop Cards Found")
    print(cardsfound)
    print (52 - counter1,"Left to find...")
    cv2.imwrite("C:/FlopOne/" + cardFound + ".jpg")

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

There are lots of elif statements after this all responding to getInput but when the loop gets paused for getInput. my windows (there are five of them) dont turn up there just grey screen. however, if I call waitKey() in order to see my windows then the loop haults and I am stuck unable to gain input. I don't want to have to parse this folder manually.

Note I am only now learning Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with paths and directories, you should use the os.path module. (It's not required, but it makes dealing with paths much easier).  This module makes it a little easier to make cross-platorm code that will run on both windows and linux even though the directories and path conventions look different.  Below is a little example of choosing directories and writing to them.

This example has a while loop that continually asks for input as long as the input is not 'e'.  The user can write to either directory a or directory b.  From here we are appending the directory and random filename using os.path.join().  Notice that I am not using unix-style paths or windows-style paths.  If you want to run this locally, just be sure to create directory "a" and directory "b".

```
import os
from random import randint


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # This is the current working directory...
    base_path = os.getcwd()

    while True:
        # whitelist of directories...
        dirs = ["a", "b"]

        # Asking the user for the directory...
        raw_input = input("Enter directory (a, b): ")

        # Checking to be sure that the directory they entered is valid...
        if raw_input in dirs:

            # Generating a random filename that we will create and write to...
            file_name = "{0}.txt".format(randint(0, 1000000))

            # Here we are joining the base_path with the user-entered
            # directory and the randomly generated filename...
            new_file_path = os.path.join(base_path, raw_input, file_name)

            print("Writing to: {0}".format(new_file_path))

            # Writing to that randomly generated file_name/path...
            with open(new_file_path, 'w+') as out_file:
                out_file.write("Cool!")

        elif raw_input == 'e':
            break
```